# Check if a username has been registered

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using the builtin ASP.NET logon and user management features. Is there a way to just identify if a username or email address is already registered? I would've thought it's part of FormsAuthentication or similar, but can't find such a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check whether [`Membership.GetUser` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.getuser.aspx) returns a null value or not.

If you want to create a new user and you're doing this check as a part of that process, try calling [`Membership.CreateUser` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152012.aspx) and check the `MembershipCreateStatus` to get the failure reason, in case it fails.

Answer (score 1):

The only correct way to do this is to actually try to register/create the user right away and handle the results of that action.  You don't have to *enable* the new user until they actually finish the registration process and can delete the account if they abandon your site before completing it, but anything else you do opens yourself up to a race condition bug.

Comment: That's a viable option only in the registration process. However, you may want to check the availability of a username with an AJAX call prior to actually submitting the form.

Comment: @Mehrdad - the thing to do there is still create the user in the ajax call.

Comment: I don't think that's worth it. It would be creating a whole bunch of accounts as the user is typing in the text field. The probability of such a race condition is not high and if that happens, you'd just ask the user to retry.